# Able to UPDATE a row on 'Button Click' when I have a dynamic table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I require some help with updating a row in table when I've pressed a button. At the moment I have a dynamic table, which fetches data from the database and posts it as a table. What I really want to do now, is to be able to UPDATE a row on button click. Here is my code.

My database (table name: assignment):

```
| ID | CustomerID | Name | Address | Technician |
```

My PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['customerButton'])){
    $ID = $row_Assignment['ID']; <--- //Not sure which ID to fetch, so it'll be unique for each customer  
    $user = $row_Users['username']; <--- // Name of the logged in user.

    mysql_query("UPDATE assignment SET technician = '$user' WHERE ID='$ID'"); <--- //Not sure what to put after 'WHERE'. 
}

?>
```

Here's a snippet of the dynamic table

```
<td><?php echo $row_Assignment['address']; ?></td>
<td>
<?php echo $row_Assignment['technician']; ?>

<form action="" method="post"> 

    <input type="submit" name="customerButton" id="customerButton" value="Add">

</form>
</td>
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to update a table full of inputs? I mean you download the table then excel like modify it and then save it back to mysql??

Comment: Yeah basically. ATM I add new assignments by filling out the required fields and display them in a table. What I basically want to be able to, is to have one of my technicians to able to take the assigment by pressing the button. (If that makes sense)...

Comment: You should use a framework like Symphony for this. It will generate all the programming skeleton to create, read, update and delete (CRUD) table records for you without programming a single line of code. All you have to do is follow some conventions when naming the database tables and fields. Then you start a process called "scaffolding" and the framework will generate all the basic code for you that you can use as is our extend and modify to your needs.

Comment: I'll take a look into that, thanks. But I kind have a deadtime on this project, and I'm afraid I not will be able to learn/modify my current project. But I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a hidden value of ID in your html like so

```
<td>
<?php echo $row_Assignment['technician']; ?>

<form action="" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="assignment_id" value="".$row_Assignment['ID']."">
    <input type="submit" name="customerButton" id="customerButton" value="Add">

</form>
</td>
```

Then on your php code for updating you could easily identify which row was submitted by getting the id as such

```
$ID = $_POST['assignment_id'];
```

Then you can use that $ID in the where condition of the update and set whatever value you need to set for the columns you need to update.

Comment: Thanks that worked! May I ask you about one more thing? I'd really like to have the button to disappear IF the row (technician) != NULL. Kind of annoying to have a button there, when a technician already have choosen to take the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to update a table full of inputs? I mean you download the table then excel like modify it and save it back.

Make your table to be full of inputs inside the tds, except for the id which should be in a hidden input
then you will use an array to send this information when you post meaning for example

```
  <td><input name='name[]'></td><td><input name='comments[]'></td>...etc
```

this way when you post

```
   $_POST['name']=// a list of the values then you just have to update each row  so...
```

update with a foreach in your php

```
   foreach($_POST['name'] as $key=>$value){
      $ID = $_POST['id'][$key]; 
         $name = value;
         $comments = $_POST['comments'][$key];

          mysql_query("UPDATE assignment SET technician = '$name',comments='$comments' WHERE ID='$ID'");

   }
```

This approach will update the whole table

Comment: I will take a look into this shortly. Bit busy atm :)